# Quick Question on Production Possibilities Frontier Curve

Tags: supply-and-demand, preferences, production-function, demographics

Can someone please tell me how or why the curve shifts outward.

In the textbook, I was given that:

"But if we cut production of mobile phones to 3 million this year, we can produce 2 mobile phone factories at point K."

"Then next year, our PPF shifts outward because we have more capital"

I might be wrong here, but is it saying that because we reduced production of mobile phones, we can use the spare $$$, to invest in capital resources to speed up/increase the production of mobile phones next year?

If so, then why is it talking about 2 mobile phones at point K if we reduce production cost to 3 million. Is this related to the outward shift?

Also, why is the curve asymmetric?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we requested clarification from the OP 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I chose not to vote to close this question, because I think it is a good opportunity to showcase how important it is for the OPs to offer *comprehensive input* related to their question.

What goes wrong here?

As is and with the input given by OP, the pictured Production Possibility Frontier is *totally wrong*. Why? Because it appears to represent a substitution effect between resources/goods, where the one (factories to make mobile phones) is *necessary* for the production of the other (mobile phones). So for example the point where the blue line cuts the horizontal axis appears to be saying:

> *"If we eliminate factories for mobile phones, we can produce 5 million
>   mobile phones".*

I find hard to believe that the textbook authors are that incompetent, so there must be more to the story -and the OP should provide this additional input, otherwise the question should rightfully be closed.

Comment: Okay then. As a further input, I found that the line "why is the curve asymmetric?" indicated that the OP did not spend enough time on the question and does not really know *what* he is asking. I could be wrong, but it is the OP's burden to make his question clear.

Comment: @denesp Indeed, it would appear so. Let's see if we will get any reaction from the OP.